# Sampling effort in a logistic regression (glm in R)

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I would like to take into account the sampling effort in a logistic regression (in R) to give more or less weight to observations, but I don’t know how to do it. I have read many topics on the “weigths” parameter in glm but this seems not suitable in my case. I have a dataset with presence or absence at different location and the sampling effort vary between locations. I have a raster map that estimate the sampling effort at each location (depending on the number of potential observers in each area) but I don´t have precise information for each site such as the exact number of visit and the result of each visit (presence or absence). I would like to build a species distribution model based on different environmental predictors but taking into account the differences in sampling effort. Is someone have an idea on how to specify this in a glm?

Comment: how have you done it in the end? I am stuck on a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to consider the sampling effort, the [`svyglm` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/3.32-1/topics/svyglm) should be a good option. 
`svyglm` computes the robust standard errors which consider the loss of precision introduced by sampling weights.

Before using `svyglm`, you might specify your survey design with the [`svydesign` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/3.32-1/topics/svydesign).

Comment: Thanks! I will read the documentation on this function. I had a brief look and it could be useful! But I still need to understand in detail how to specify the survey design.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the sampling effort in each location as an offset? Just add an `offset =` term in to your glm formula.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Maybe but I am not sure to understand well in which case we should or not use an offset. I will try to find more information on this, to see if this can be suitable in my case.But thanks for the suggestion!